# uniform edge extrude - geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

does anybody have an idea how to extrude line to both sides, like on image?

I tried to find something similar but couldn't and cannot figure how to do it. Curve to mesh doesn't fit because I need to maintain multiple connections.

Maybe something like simulating "skin modifier" and then just scaling it by 0 at Z axis going to work?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this?   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/281083/how-to-extrude-edges-along-their-normals